# Populate grid from drop down with multiple select

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid which is populated based on selection from a drop down box.
It works fine but I need to modify the drop down to be multi-selectable as to allow the user to choose more than one entry. How can it be done?

**HTML**

```
<select name="prov_id" id="prov_id" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="25_3″>agnico</option>
  <option value="24_3″>agnico2</option>
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$myGrid.jqGrid(
{
  url: myURL + '?method=GetTransactions', //CFC that will return the transactions
  postData: {
  prID: function() { return $("#prov_id option:selected").val(); },
  mn: function() { return $("#month option:selected").val(); },
  yr: function() { return $("#year option:selected").val(); }
},
//multiselect: true,  //adds checkboxes in front of each line
//multiboxonly: true,
datatype: 'json',     //We specify that datatype we will be using is JSON
colNames: [
  'Trx ID',
  'Description',
  'Cheque No',
  'Amount', 
  'Debit',
  'Credit', 
  'Month', 
  'Year', 
  'Status',
  'Added by Employee'
],
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone interested I solved this issue:

> ```
> function getSelProv(){
>    return  $('select#prov_id').val();
> }
> .......
> ```

```
postData: { 
  prID: function() { return getSelProv() },
........
```